# Returning the result of a subquery as a field

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery

I am essentially trying to return the result of a subquery in a field of my outer query like so:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field8 = (SELECT * FROM TABLE)
FROM OTHERTABLE
```

I found an example of my intended functionality [here](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery) but it doesn't seem to work on mariadb (which from what I can gather is just mysql). Is there a way to do this with mysql or am I missing something? I'm getting an "Unknown column 'field8' in 'field list'".

I'm using a node mysql module and I hope to achieve

```
[{
   field1: something,
   field2: somethingelse,
   field8: [{
              data, data, data
           },{
              data, data, data
           }] 
}]
```

If this isn't possible, I can always perform two separate queries

Comment: The syntax is `SELECT field1, field2, (mysubquery) as field8 FROM OTHERTABLE`, but the subquery must return only 1 row and 1 column. Have to look at `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`, but your query seems off. Consider using separate queries.

Comment: @Bohemian JSON_ARRAYAGG seems to be what I'm looking for, do you mind throwing that up as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the syntax, and use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to convert the rowset to json:

```
SELECT
    field1,
    field2,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG((SELECT * FROM TABLE)) as field8
FROM OTHERTABLE
GROUP BY field1, field2
```